# What are the limits and what counts as "other gods" as referred to in Exodus 23:13?

Tags: exodus, god

Let me quote Exodus 23:13 NKJV

> 13 “And in all that I have said to you, be circumspect and make no
> mention of the name of other gods, nor let it be heard from your
> mouth.

My question comes with a few. First is, what all counts as "other gods"? Also, what were the limits of this command? Was it only restricted to the sabbath as perhaps hinted by the previous verses or could you simply not mention the name of another god at all, at any time?

Finally, how does this, if at all, apply to us today and how literal should we take this?

Comment: gods that are not Almighty count as other gods. The. Almighty YHWH is the only God of gods. He is the only true God, Jeremiah 10:17 and John 17:3

Comment: "Other gods" included anything other than Jehovah.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, it should be mentioned that "make no mention" is not a universally recognized translation. Many translators render this phrase as "do not invoke" or "thou shalt not call upon," etc. In fact the Bible itself makes mention of many other deities, so it stands to reason that the Israelites - in reading the scripture aloud - would speak these names, and also that they would have occasion to say them occasionally in conversations with others. So I would say that the limits were not absolute. These gods are not an example of "he shall not be named," but "he/she that shall not be invoked."  As for the other questions:

- What all counts as "other gods"?

Any deity other than YHWH, but he may be called by other names: El, Elhohim, El-Shaddai, Adonai (the Lord), Ha-Shem (the Name), etc.

- What were the limits of this command? Was it only restricted to the sabbath as perhaps hinted by the previous verses or could you simply not mention the name of another god at all, at any time?

Although the context is keeping the sabbath, this command is general. Other gods are not to be called upon ever. This is clear from many other scriptural verses.

- Finally, how does this, if at all, apply to us today and how literal should we take this?

This is a matter of personal belief and opinion. Orthodox Jews do not even mention that name of God himself, let alone other gods. Indeed, most Christians (perhaps without knowing it) do likewise when they read the Bible and substitute "the Lord" for YHWH. However, since the verse does not actually prohibit mentioning other deities in my opinion, their names may be spoken. On the other hand, they should not be invoked or called upon. For example, a believer should not curse another by saying: "May Zeus strike you," or invoke the name a deity other than God in seeking healing or blessing another.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the well thought out and clear answer. The clarification between "mention" and "invoke" makes the verse make more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

On this matter, the OT teaching is singular and persistent - there is only ONE God and that God is Jehovah, YHWH.  Specifically:

- Deut 4:35 - You were shown these things so that you would know that **the LORD** is God; there is **no other besides Him**.
- Deut 6:4 - Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is One.
- Deut 32:39 - See now that I am He; there is **no God besides Me**. I bring death and I give life; I wound and I heal, and there is no one who can deliver from My hand.
- 2 Sam 7:22 - How great You are, O **Lord GOD**! For there is none like You, and there is **no God but You**, according to everything we have heard with our own ears.
- 1 Kings 8:60 - so that all the peoples of the earth may know that the LORD is God. There is **no other**!
- Isa 44:6 - Thus says the LORD, the King and Redeemer of Israel, the LORD of Hosts: “I am the first and I am the last, and there is **no God but Me**.
- Isa 45:5, 6 - I am the LORD, and there is no other; there is **no God but Me**. I will equip you for battle, though you have not known Me, 6so that all may know, from where the sun rises to where it sets, that there is none but Me; I am **the LORD, and there is no other**.
- Isa 45:14 - This is what the LORD says: “The products of Egypt and the merchandise of Cush, along with the Sabeans, men of stature, will come over to you and will be yours; they will trudge behind you; they will come over in chains and bow down to you. They will confess to you: ‘God is indeed with you, and there is no other; there is **no other God**.’ ”
- Isa 45:18 - For thus says the LORD, who created the heavens—He is God; He formed the earth and fashioned it; He established it; He did not create it to be empty, but formed it to be inhabited: “I am the LORD, and there is no other.
- Isa 45:21, 22 - Speak up and present your case— yes, let them take counsel together. Who foretold this long ago? Who announced it from ancient times? Was it not I, the LORD? There is **no other God but Me**, a righteous God and Savior; there is none but Me. Turn to Me and be saved, all the ends of the earth; for **I am God**, and there is **no other**.
- Isa 46:9 - Remember what happened long ago, for I am God, and there is no other; **I am God, and there is none like Me**.

Thus, all other "gods" are not gods at all but pretentious frauds.  The prophet Jeremiah actually says this:

> Jer 2:11 - Has a nation ever changed its gods, though they are no gods
> at all? Yet My people have exchanged their Glory for useless idols.

Therefore, Ex 23:13 is a warning that there is no God by YHWH and thus, God's people should have nothing to do with them.

Finally, this is a timeless teaching that is as true today as when it was first uttered by the ancient prophets.

Comment: -1 Yes there is only one "God." But Hebrew lacks capitalization making it linguistically impossible to make that statement in Hebrew. The command to worship only YHVH is utterly meaningless if in fact there are not other gods with real power and real dominion over real aspects of the created world. The fact their existence is from YHVH and their power and authority is subject to YHVH does not make them less real. The NT, 2 Corinthians 4:4 clearly states there is a god (other than YHVH) of this world.

Comment: How literal is this command? If taken very literally I can imagine that evangelism to other cultures with other gods would be harder.

Comment: @Jason_ - the command is still valid, and there are plenty of other gods on offer - like materialism, money, power, etc.

Comment: @RevelationLad - obviously there are many things that people treat as gods but none are actually gods as explained above.  They are all pretentious frauds.  These include Satan, the stomach, idols, , money & power, etc.  Thus, YHWH is the only true God despite what some try to think.  Isaiah goes to some trouble to emphasize this point in Isa 41FF especially his sarcastic statement in Isa 41:23, "tell us what the future holds, so we may know that you are gods. Do something, whether good or bad, so that we will be dismayed and filled with fear."

Comment: I understand the position about the true God. That does not alter the clear statements throughout the Bible, there are others whom **Scripture** calls gods. One example Deuteronomy 10:17 *For the LORD your God is God of gods...* אלהי האלהים

Comment: @RevelationLad - such are only pretend gods in view of the clear statement listed above - these is only one God.  I agree with the Bible's monotheism.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel 10:13-21 talks about Persia and Greece having heavenly princes. Michael is the heavenly prince of Israel. As in, each nation has a guardian angel that looks after it. This could be said that each nation has its own spiritual power.

Psalm 82:1-8 and Psalm 89:6-8 imply that there are other heavenly entities beside the Jewish God, but the Jewish God is the most supreme entity.